# Roslyn Msbuildworkspace Solution Identify unit test projects

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

var msBuildWorkSpace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

var solution = msBuildWorkSpace.OpenSolutionAsync("Path to solution");

how to identify unit test projects in the loaded solution?

Can we determine based on project references
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Comment: Can we determine based on project references Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Comment: You can only do that based on project references. MSTest/NUnit/xUnit.net all have their unique references you can tell immediately.